# In $\Delta ABC$, perpendiculars $AD$ and $BF$ meet at point $H$, find $\angle HAI$, where $I$ is the incentre.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> In $\Delta ABC$, perpendiculars $AD$ and $BF$ are drawn to $BC$ and $CA$ respectively to meet at point $H$, find $\angle HAI$, where $I$ is the incentre.

This was given to me in an assignment by my teacher, but I think the information is not enough, because when I try to calculate, the variable gets cancelled :/

I get:

$$\angle AHF = 90+ \angle IAH-x$$
$$\angle HAF=x-\angle IAH$$
$$\angle AHI = 90+x - \angle IAH$$

On trying to find $\angle HAI$, I get $180=180$ :(

Please help :(

*$\angle IAC =BAI= x$

---

*Diagram for reference:*

[image]

Is my diagram correct ?

Comment: What do you mean by $x$ here?

Comment: $\angle IAC =BAI= x$

Comment: I drew a diagram, I'll attach that too in a while

Comment: When you say you need to find $\angle HAI$, what do you mean? In terms of $\angle A$ and $\angle B$ (or $\angle C$)? You should state that in the question. If so, make use of the fact that $I$ is the intersection of angle bisectors of the angles in triangle $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: @MathLover I have written whatever the question specifies. There is no information further than what I have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\triangle DAB$, $\angle HAB=\angle DAB=90-\angle B$. Since $I$ lies on the bisector of $\angle A$, $\angle IAB=\frac{\angle A}{2}$. Hence $$\angle HAI=\angle HAB-\angle IAB=90^{\circ}-\angle B-\frac{\angle A}{2}=\frac{\angle C-\angle B}{2} \implies |\angle HAI|=\frac{|\angle B-\angle C|}{2}$$ I think we need $\angle B-\angle C$ to find out the final answer.

Comment: why did you add the mod in the last step?

Comment: because, generally we deal with non directed angles. If I say $\angle HAI=\frac{\angle C-\angle B}{2}$ then it would mean directed angle $\angle HAI$ since it can be negative too. When we add absolute value sign, then we mean that this value is the magnitude of that angle. I hope it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Drop a erpendicular from I on AC and mark it as E. In triangle AIE draw a line from I parallel with AD , it intersect AC at G. Clearly:

$\angle AIG=\angle HAI\Rightarrow \angle AIE=\angle HAI+\angle AHF=90-\frac A2$

A means $\angle BAC$. we also have:

$\angle DHF=360-(2\times 90+\angle BCA)=180-\angle BCA$

$\Rightarrow AHF 180-DHF=180-(180-\angle BCA)=\angle BCA$

$\Rightarrow HAI=90-\frac A2-\angle AHF=90-(C+\frac A2)$

where C means $\angle BCA$